# Is this correlation statistically significant?

Tags: statistics, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a dataframe:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 69.26 |
| 1 | 74.91 |
| 1.5 | 77.21 |
| 2 | 77.52 |

I run

```
cor, pval = pearsonr( data["A"],  data["B"])
```

Answer is:
correlation coeficient = 0.91  and p-value = 0.09

My significance level alpha = 0.05. How do I interpret such result? Is data correlating?

I am asking because I have found several sources which deny each other. One says p-value should be small and another says high in order to say that correlation exists.

Also, I would like to know the coefficient for which I can say for sure that data correlates. For example if coef. 0.9 is quite high can I assert that it still corelates but with coefficient 0.4 for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case: No, there's no significant correlation, because your p value (which is the computed probability for the null hypothesis, namely that the connection between the two variables is the result of random fluctuations rather than a causal link) is 9 % and therefore higher than the chosen significance value of 5 %.

Note that this is not a matter of Scipy; it's a matter of interpreting the results that your statistical analysis has given you.

Also note that it would be methodologically wrong to change the significance threshold to 10 % now. Under that threshold the results would indeed be statistically significant, but proper methodology demands that you set the applicable threshold *beforehand* and then compare the results against it, not that you adjust afterwards to make your results fit a desired outcome.

Comment: Thank you for quick response! Yes, I understand its a matter of interpretation but I just dont know how to interpret it. I mean, I see in a data (which is shown in a question) that variable do correlate. When, A increases, B also does.

Comment: Yes, the correlation exists, it's simply not a statistically significant one. Rather, your result shows that the null hypothesis (which holds that the correlation between A and B is the result of pure chance rather than a causal link) cannot be rejected. The probability would have to be below 5 % to reject it, but you have 9 %.

Comment: But if I have only 4 rows of data in my investigation can I make a conclusion that correlation exists EMPIRICALLY? And for those cases when p < 0.05 I can conclude that correlation exists FOR SURE?

Comment: Correlation exists, because correlation simply means that the two variables tend to move together, either in the same direction (positive correlation) or in reverse directions (negative correlation). This you can observe empirically. But correlation does not necessarily imply causation. What you want to know is if there is a causal link between the two variables. You cannot observe this empirically. All you can do is use statistical models to estimate the probability that the observed correlation is the result of pure chance, and then  compare that probability against a pre-defined threshold.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now. Can it also be that I dont have enough data to strongly assert there is correlation? Because I was investigating A and B thinking that it correlates and now it cannot claim that for sure anymore. So maybe its because its only 4 lines of data?

Comment: Yes, that has certainly something to do with it. n = 4 is extremely low and hardly reliable enough to make any assertions; this also drives up your p. If you get a larger sample, you get more reliable results, and if the correlation still shows, p should be much lower (possibly dropping below your 5 % threshold).

Comment: In your case, a P value is the probability that you would observe such a level of correlation if there was no correlation in the population you are sampling from (i.e., if the null hypothesis was true). The correlation you observed (.91) is still strong; your P value does not refute that, so you cannot conclude there is no correlation. Whether you should conclude that there is correlation is an entirely different topic.

Comment: @DrGo You're confusing correlation and causation in your comment. The correlation indubitably exists; it has been observed empirically. But this does not mean there is necessarily causation. The p value is the probability that the observed correlation is the result of chance fluctuations rather than an existing causal link between the two variables.

Comment: @Schnitte the last sentence of my comment should have been "Whether you should conclude that there is CAUSATION is an entirely different topic." Does that clear things up for you? In the sentence prior to that I said "The correlation you observed (.91) is still strong; your P value does not refute that, so you cannot conclude there is no correlation" agreeing with that there is correlation.